# How to authorize requests with x-auth-token in its header using asp.net core api?

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I generated token included user info and her roles using asp.net core web api and get it at client, then put it in x-auth-token in request header. How cal I authorize user (with her roles) in asp.net api controllers and actions? My setting in startup.cs is like below but I can not catch request in my action!

```
var securityKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SECURITY_KEY");
var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey));

services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
              {
               ValidateIssuer = true,
               ValidateAudience = true,
               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

               ValidIssuer = "shoniz.com",
               ValidAudience = "readers",
               IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey
              };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example is an settings of authentication (JWT scheme). First, you have to add middleware, which will authenticate user. This part of code should be present in `Startup.cs` (`Configure()` method).

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Once this middleware is called, all the authentication schemes are taken into account. When the authentication will success, `HttpContext.User` will be set (including all your issues claims).

**The second part is authorization.** The simplest way is to use `[Authorize]` attribute you can use as an annotation along with your action methods and controllers. You can add custom role names or policy restriction.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class CmsControllerBase : Controller
{
}
```